# Multiple Page Orientions - Tools for Adobe Postscript

Tags: java, adobe, postscript

I'm delving into Tools for Adobe Postscript, and I'm trying to find a way to generate a document with multiple orientations.

Example:

page 1's orientation is portrait, and page 2's orientation is landscape.

Below I attempt to create a new page and then set the page dimensions opposite of what they were before, so that height becomes width and width becomes height - effectively creating a landscape view. This does not work, however, and I was wondering if there is a way to do it at all.

```
    OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);


    try {
        //Instantiate the EPSDocumentGraphics2D instance
        PSDocumentGraphics2D g2d = new PSDocumentGraphics2D(false);
        g2d.setGraphicContext(new org.apache.xmlgraphics.java2d.GraphicContext());

        //Set up the document size
        g2d.setupDocument(out, pageWidthPT, pageHeightPT);

        g2d.setFont(new Font(font, Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
        g2d.drawString("           !", 10, 10);

        g2d.nextPage();
        g2d.setViewportDimension(pageHeightPT, pageWidthPT);

        g2d.drawString("Hello World!", 10, 20);
        System.out.println("Creating the document");
        g2d.finish();//Cleanup
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you attempt to use the code you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `nextPage()`, instead of `setViewportDimension()` use `setupDocument()`, passing in the same `OutputStream` and swapping the width and height: `g2d.setupDocument(out, pageHeightPT, pageWidthPT);`

EDIT

The problem with calling `setupDocument()` is that it resets the page count and generates file headers again.  Instead, you can extend `PSDocumentGraphics2D` and add your own `setDimension()` method:

```
public class MyPSDocumentGraphics2D extends PSDocumentGraphics2D {
    public MyPSDocumentGraphics2D(PSDocumentGraphics2D psDocumentGraphics2D) {
        super(psDocumentGraphics2D);
    }

    public MyPSDocumentGraphics2D(boolean b, OutputStream outputStream, int i, int i1) throws IOException {
        super(b, outputStream, i, i1);
    }

    public MyPSDocumentGraphics2D(boolean b) {
        super(b);
    }

    public void setDimension(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

In `MyPSDocumentGraphics2D`, `this.width` and `this.height` refer to protected member properties of `AbstractPSDocumentGraphics2D`.

You can tie this in to your example by instantiating `MyPSDocumentGraphics2D` and then replacing `g2d.setViewportDimension(pageHeightPT, pageWidthPT);` with `g2d.setDimension(pageHeightPT, pageWidthPT);`:

```
OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(outputFile);
out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);


try {
    //Instantiate my extension of the EPSDocumentGraphics2D instance
    MyPSDocumentGraphics2D g2d = new MyPSDocumentGraphics2D(false);
    g2d.setGraphicContext(new org.apache.xmlgraphics.java2d.GraphicContext());

    //Set up the document size
    g2d.setupDocument(out, pageWidthPT, pageHeightPT);

    g2d.setFont(new Font(font, Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
    g2d.drawString("           !", 10, 10);

    g2d.nextPage();
    // change the page orientation
    g2d.setDimension(pageHeightPT, pageWidthPT);

    g2d.drawString("Hello World!", 10, 20);
    System.out.println("Creating the document");
    g2d.finish();//Cleanup
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
}
```